# Using an incrementing variable in a bash command line for loop?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using a bash commandline for-loop to concat a group of files together, and I'd like to append an incrementing digit.

Something like this:

```
j=1;for i in *.bak; do echo {$j++: >> files.grp;cat $i >> files.grp; echo }, >> files.grp; done
```

So the output would like this:

```
{1:"file1 contents"},{2:"file2 contents"},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
j=$(($j+1))
```

or use

```
$((j++))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# file1.bak
hallo

# some other file.bak
H?llo*

# a!file.bak
new!
line"
```

Processed with the script:

```
j=1
for i in *.bak; do
  echo "{$((j++)):$(cat "$i")}" >> files.grp
done
```

Writes the following in files.grp:

```
{1:hallo}
{2:H?llo*}
{3:new!
line"}
```

Comment: Oh very nice. Can you explain what `$(cat "$i")` is doing? That is, I understand what the output of that will be, based on your example, but what does that syntax mean?

Comment: This is called command substitution. `$(command)` will execute `command` and print the output of it (if any). In this case, `echo` will receive the output of `cat "$i"` as an input and processes that further. See the section 'Command Substitution' in `man bash`